# CURL not sending cookies with POST request

Tags: post, cookies, curl

I have enabled cookie engine in curl using curl_easy_setopt on CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.

In the response from server, the cookies are set.

In subsequent requests, CURL is not sending cookies along with the request only if it is a POST request. For GET requests CURL is sending cookies along.

Should I indicate CURL in some other way for POST requests so it would send cookies.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: In which language is this? You need to show some code.

Answer (score 1):

[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCOOKIEFILE) and [CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCOOKIEJAR) are both enough on their own to activate the cookie "engine". However, only CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE will read cookies from a file and only CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR will make any cookies get written to a file.

Your question doesn't really say, but if subsequent requests are using the same easy handle then it will deal with cookies after being enabled.

[CURLOPT_VERBOSE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTVERBOSE) and [CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTDEBUGFUNCTION) are your friends to better track what headers curl sends and receives.